# Cannot Read Saved Opencv Mat Image in C++ From Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I would like to save an OpenCV Mat image as byte data in txt file in C++. Then, I want to read that file in Java and obtain this image. 
My C++ code:

```
std::ofstream tileData;

tileData.open("image.txt", std::ios::app | 
std::ios::binary);

cv::Mat temp = imread("image.png",1);

std::vector<uchar> array(temp.rows * temp.cols);
array.assign(temp.datastart, temp.dataend);

tileData.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(array.data()), sizeof(uchar)*array.size());


tileData.close();
```

My Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        File file = new File("image.txt");
        byte[] buf = getBytesFromFile(file);

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
    }


    // Returns the contents of the file in a byte array.
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
            throw new IOException("File is too large!");
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            while (offset < bytes.length
                    && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

When I debug the Java code, it says img is null. Could you offer a solution to read this txt file in Java?

Comment: My solutions would be to write a program in Java and if there is a problem, then I would post my code here and ask a specific question to that problem.

Comment: I rearranged the question @ThomasSablik

Comment: You can't us ImageIO. You are using your own image format. How should ImageIO know, how to read it? You have to read the text file byte-wise and fill an array with it. I would use openCV for Java for this task.

Comment: You are right. I can use OpenCV in Java. However, I need image data as BufferedImage in Java. Thus, it will require extra copying data from Mat to BufferedImage. I have thousands of images for this task. It will slow down the process. Could you offer another solution?

Comment: You can't use the file format you are currently using. E. g. your image.txt contains following entries: `5 7 5 6`. Is it an image of size 2x2, 1x4 or 4x1? You need meta information in your file. If you add meta information, you can also use a file format like PNG, JPEG or BITMAP. Why do you read the image with C++, write it to byte data file and read this data with Java? Why don't you read the image with Java?

Comment: Those images come from OpenSlide which is a reader of pyramid image in C++. Then, I process those images and send the results to Java. Actually, I accomplished this task by encoding Mat data to PNG format. Then, I serialized the encoded data to txt and could read it from Java. However, it takes time to encode thousands of images

Comment: Then encode Mat data to Bitmap without compression. That should be as fast as writing the data to byte text file. You should check if your image format is supported by ImageIO

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the speed of encoding to bitmap is faster than encoding to PNG. However, writing encoded bitmap data to txt file is slower because of its size.

Comment: Bitmap and byte text file should have nearly the same file size since both methods encode each pixel as one value without compression. The only overhead in bitmaps is image size and some other meta information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ImageIO to read the byte text file. You are using your own image format without meta information like size. Either you add meta information to your byte file and use your own custom image format or you use an image format with very simple encoding and without compression like Bitmap. It contains all information ImageIO needs and it should have nearly the same file size and performance as your method.